# Custom elements - hide an element before it can render

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using custom elements, is it possible to have an element's display set to none (or in any other way) before it renders? Consider that I am using this particular one as a base class for other elements, so applying a global style won't work.

The element is simple

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

And it doesn't do much :)

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {} 
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

But a lot of others extend it

```html
<my-other-element></my-other-element>
```

```js
class MyOtherElement extends MyElement {}
customElements.define('my-other-element', MyOtherElement);
```

This is why I could not have a global css rule

```css
my-element {
  display:none;
}
```

I thought I got smart and added a shadow dom with a `<style>` and `:host` style but this just makes any other HTML I've placed inside my elements disappear.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

With the [`:defined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:defined) pseudo class, which is part of the Web Components spec, you can apply styles whenever the custom element has been successfully defined.

```
my-element {
  display: none;
}

my-element:defined {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, my extended elements won't inherit those styles. Unless I'm wrong, but my tests show it does not, which really sucks!

Comment: That is correct, these styles won't be inherited, because CSS doesn't work like that. You could either set a class on every custom element that needs this behavior or style each custom element individually.

Comment: :< sadface. Ok tanks